# Spinner.setSelection() not setting position

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am setting spinner position in my app's spinner. It sets till I'm using my app but as soon as I close my app and open it again or if I close it from the the background running app, the spinner sets to default. what might be the reason?

here's my code:

```
 public boolean setTdpId(ArrayList<String> tdpList) {
    try {
        tdpIdList = tdpList;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
                tdpidSpinner = new Spinner(Activity_Settings.this);
                rowTdpid.setLongClickable(true);
                TableRow.LayoutParams tdpid_spinner_params = new 
 TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f);
                tdpidSpinner.setLayoutParams(tdpid_spinner_params);
                rowTdpid.addView(tdpidSpinner);
                tdpidSpinner.setPrompt("Select TdpId");
                tdpidSpinner.setLongClickable(true);
                tdpidSpinner.setClickable(true);

                if (tdpIdList != null && tdpIdList.size() > 0) {
                if (screenSize.equalsIgnoreCase("large")) {
                     spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            Activity_Settings.this,
                            R.layout.spinner_custom_textview, tdpIdList);
                    }else{
                        spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                Activity_Settings.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
 tdpIdList);
                    }
                    tdpidSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

                    String tdpid = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(
                            Utility.PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                            .getString(Utility.TDPID, "");

                    if (tdpid != "") {
                        int spinnerPosition = spinnerAdapter
                                .getPosition(tdpid);
                        tdpidSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
                        tdpidSpinner.setEnabled(false);

                    }

                }

            }

        });
        tdpidTv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                tdpidSpinner.setEnabled(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want??? Selected value should always display on the spinner?? Or default value should display on the spinner whenever we comes to that screen??

Comment: You need to use **SharedPreferences**

Comment: i think you get value from shared preference but you will not stored value in it.so may be give null value and your condition will not execute

Comment: Assign value to spinner in onResume method. it will call always.

Comment: Android will allocate the memory to the foreground program, during this your app's ui may lose the data, save data and reuse data by program. save the data on screen when `onPause()`, and refresh the ui when is `onResume()`.

Comment: I am getting value from shared preference but the position is not setting. I want to set the shared pref value's position once I had set. and this method is being called in inCreate()

Comment: @SheenaTyagi i think it take Position  integer and from shared pref you get string

Comment: @VishalHalani Yes I'm getting string from shared pref and setting int position by getting the position of that string in adapter and I'm getting "-1" as position when i close my app and opens it again

Comment: @SheenaTyagi  what position you want to show??

Comment: I want to show the position of the string I'm getting from shared pref.. Suppose initially spinner has items: "A","B","C" and i selected item "B" and saved it in shared pref. Then whenever I come back to the app, shared pref will get value "B" and spinner should set its value to "B"

Comment: @SheenaTyagi you have to store selected Indices in shared prefrence